# In the Star Trek universe is Christmas still celebrated in the 23rd and 24th centuries?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-tos

Considering we're in the Festive Season at the moment, it got me thinking about Christmas.  I don't recall any 'Christmas specials' in any *Star Trek* series, so my question is: **is Christmas referenced in any of the *Star Trek* series in such a way that implies they actually do still observe Christmas in both (or either) the 23rd and/or 24th centuries?**  This therefore excludes *Enterprise* as that is set in the 22nd century, not the 23rd or 24th century.

Comment: Thank you all for not commenting; please comment to your heart's content 

Comment: See also: [Do Earth religions persist in Star Trek?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13533/do-earth-religions-persist-in-star-trek)

Comment: @N_Soong You mad hatter! D-:

Comment: After how well the Star Wars Christmas Special went, do you really blame Roddenberry for avoiding it like the plague?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### 23rd Century - Yup

> **BERKELEY:** *Locked in, sir. Ready to beam down.*
>
> **NOEL:** *Doctor Helen Noel, Captain. **We've met. Don't you remember the science lab Christmas party?***
>
> **KIRK:** *Yes, I remember.*
>
> <sub><sup>TOS: [Dagger of the Mind](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/11.htm)</sup></sub>

### 24th Century - Yup

> **CHAKOTAY:** *I already gave them a Voyager medallion. They seemed appreciative.*
>
> **JANEWAY:** *Come in. **Doesn't it look like Christmas morning in here, Commander?***
>
> **CHAKOTAY:** *You have to admit the generosity of our guests is very impressive.*
>
> <sub><sup>VOY: [Survival Instinct](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/601.htm)</sup></sub>

---

And moving down to the (frankly laughable) EU, we see the Enterprise crew enjoying an xmas skiing celebration on the holodeck in [TNG: Spirit in the Sky!](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Spirit_in_the_Sky!)

[image]

Comment: Sad to learn that 200 years form now we will still have to suffer through holiday parties with coworkers.

Comment: @DA. - If its any consolation, the Blish novelisation indicates that she got hilariously drunk and had to be carried back to her room by Kirk. You know it's a good party when you get so blotto that you humiliate yourself in front of everyone you work with *and* your boss

Comment: So he met someone called “Noel” at a Christmas party.

Comment: @CarstenS - No-one has ever accused Star Trek of being well written.

Comment: It seems so unlike Geordi to tell someone "turn around and enjoy the view" in such a sexually suggestive way. My kids are just getting into comics, and of course I love Star Trek, but thanks for the insight into this so I know to steer them away from any Star Trek comics! :O

Comment: @corsiKlauseHoHoHo - Please never read [season one of the TNG comics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hCWiB.jpg). They do get better after that though, I promise.

Answer (score 15):

Not exactly the best answer, but an indication that I've just remembered whilst writing this up was a scene from *Star Trek Generations* whilst Picard was in the Nexus:

The Christmas tree and other decorations show conclusively that Picard is in a place where Christmas is being celebrated.  Judging by the clothing though, it doesn't look like the 23rd or 24th centuries to me though.

This provides some indication that Christmas *may* have been celebrated in the 24th century.  However, Picard actually isn't in the 24th (or 23rd) century at that time.

If another answer provides more definitive proof of Christmas being celebrated in the 23rd or 24th century, that will be a more suitable answer for this question.

Comment: Hat-whoring should not be rewarded

Comment: If you watch carefully, you'll see one of the children playing with what appears to be a futuristic jet toy. Given that one of the children is his nephew from the 24th century, I think it's safe to say this takes place in that time.

Answer (score 0):

I remember in one of the early movies, Kirk received a printed book for Christmas. I think it may have been the Wrath of Khan.

Comment: You're probably thinking of *Wrath of Khan* where Kirk gets a book from Spock for his birthday