# Why are there no Jews in the Star Trek universe?

Tags: star-trek

*Star Trek* is famous for its multiculturalism: Chekov is Russian, Sulu is Japanese, Uhura is Swahili, being Afro-American is an important factor in Sisko's identity, Chakotay is Native American, Scotty is Scottish, O'Brien is Irish, Picard is French. Yet one ethnic group is notably missing from all iterations of the series: the Jews.

This is made even stranger by the fact that so many *Star Trek* actors were Jews. (William Shatner, Leonard Nimoy, Walter Koenig, Brent Spiner, Armin Shimerman, to name a few.)

Is there any explanation for why there are no Jews in *Star Trek*, not even as minor characters? No family names like *Rosenberg* or *Cohen* among the crew, nothing. Where have all the Jews disappeared to?

To clarify, I'm curious about both an in-universe and a real-life answer, if there is one.

Comment: http://jewishjournal.com/opinion/164916/

Comment: I don't really know anything about Star Trek, but according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulcan_salute) the Vulcan salute is based on Judaism: 
*The Vulcan salute is a hand gesture popularized by the 1960s television series Star Trek. It consists of a raised hand with the palm forward and the thumb extended, while the fingers are parted between the middle and ring finger. Leonard Nimoy from the series based the gesture on the Jewish Priestly Blessing.*

Comment: I'm not a Star Trek super-fan, but I have seen most of the episodes of most of the shows, and I can't remember any character who is specifically mentioned to be Christian, Muslim, Hindu, Atheist, or anything else. So it's not like Judaism is singled out.

Comment: Sisko can better be described specifically as Louisiana Creole than just a general "Afro-American".

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I have been watching all of the episodes of the Star Trek series recently (I am TNG S6 E10) In up to there the only mention of something close to a Earth religion being followed by the crew was in S2 E4 of The Originals where Kirk says "We have no need for gods. We find the one adequate". I always found this quite strange since the show never said anything like that again, up to where I am. In both marriage scenes I have seen religion and god were not mentioned.

Comment: [Related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13533/do-earth-religions-persist-in-star-trek)

Comment: @NikolayArabadzhi Judaism, Christianity, and Islam all worship the same god. Roddenberry may have imagined that along with unification of earth politics, the religions may have merged by then as well. But actually, I suspect he just didn't think 1960's viewers would accept an atheist society.

Comment: Discussion about whether Jews are an ethnic or religious group has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82376/discussion-on-question-by-galastel-why-are-there-no-jews-in-the-star-trek-univer). Please continue the discussion there instead (and remember to [be nice](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/conduct)).

Comment: @NikolayArabadzhi That line was a result of executive meddling.

Comment: This would have been more interesting if it was about Hindus, or Chinese. Both of which are more numerous than ethnic Jews and neither of which were included in the ST universe (except for the evil bioengineering Sikhs)

Comment: If we're looking at "Jews as an ethnic group", are you counting Israelis?  That was, after all, Deanna Troi's accent, and she sure didn't get it from her mother...  Considering that Khan Noonien Singh was Indian, there seems to have been quite the ethnic shift/blending in some areas of the world.

Comment: @Chronocidal: But not all Israelis are Jews, whether ethnically or religiously.

Comment: If you want to go along the "forgotten" groups you'd notice that Australia is (and Aboriginals are) often missing/not represented in most things... :) You can't get every different [Insert label here] group represented on everything or you'd end up with more characters then minutes in the show/film.

Comment: how you define ethnics? Guinan wasn't a beta israel?

Comment: @aloMalbarez Unless I'm much mistaken, Guinan wasn't even human. Wasn't she El-Aurian?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

### In part, active omission

Other answers have addressed the fact that atheism was a central feature of *Star Trek*, except when network meddling imposed religion (for instance, Kirk saying that "we find the one [God] sufficient"). But it seems to go beyond that.

Most of the information is covered [here](http://jewishjournal.com/opinion/164916/) (credit to Valorum for the link).

- Rodenberry seems to have had some degree of anti-Semitic sentiment. Here  Sheldon Teitelbaum recounts an encounter with him.

  > The congenial Roddenberry concluded what I later realized was a slow
  >   burn. “You Jews,” he snarled, “have a lamentable habit of identifying
  >   those characteristics in a society that you deem positive and then
  >   taking credit for inventing them.”
- He also quotes Leonard Nimoy on Roddenberry's attitudes:

  > “Gene was anti-Semitic, clearly,” Nimoy replied as my heart sank.
  >   “Roddenberry had Jewish associates; Bill (Shatner) and I were both
  >   Jewish, as were others. To be fair, Roddenberry was anti-religion. And
  >   apart from being a ethnic-cultural entity, Jews, to him, were a
  >   religious group. But I saw examples not only of him practicing
  >   anti-Semitism, but of him being callous about other peoples'
  >   differences as well.”

In light of these opinions it seems easy to see that he wouldn't want to portray Jews positively; in light of his desire to avoid portraying religion in general, the easiest solution would be not to portray them at all:

- > What, for instance, are we to make of Roddenberry's decision to
  >   rewrite screenwriter Shimon Wincelberg's reference to Hillel's “Torah 
  >   on one leg” parable in the classic first-season-episode, “Dagger of
  >   the Mind,”, attributing it to “the ancient skeptic.”

This "policy" continued past Roddenberry's era, when at least some other producers took a similar stance: not necessarily because of personal anti-Semitism, but because of the perceptions of the audience:

- > “It was a subject of extraordinary discussion,” the late executive
  >   producer Michael Piller recounted. “The orders were handed down not to
  >   make Worf's adopted parents Jewish. I don't want to sound
  >   anti-Semitic; that's not what it meant. I am a Jew and so is Rick
  >   (Producer Rick Berman). We were simply afraid of making the Worf
  >   character laughable.”

In acknowledging that a Russian Jewish character would be perceived as "laughable," the producers essentially were bowing to the prejudices of the time: why would a Jewish character be laughable, but not a Christian one?

In light of these facts, it seems likely that both Roddenberry's personal attitudes (initially) and the attempts of producers to play to audiences (later) played a role in the relative<sup>1</sup> lack of Jews in Star Trek.

<sub>1: As noted elsewhere, the number of Jews in *Star Trek* is not *necessarily* underrepresentative of the world population. Rather,  the prejudices of Roddenberry and others caused them to be underrepresented relative to their proportion among the actors and their proportion of the *US* population, roughly 2%—two more common referents for Hollywood producers.</sub>

---

A brief note about the Ferengi. To some people, the Ferengi are the most obvious examples of Jewish stereotypes in *Star Trek* (to some, it's the Vulcans, whom Nimoy seems to have intended to portray more positively). At least some people associated with these show have echoed these concerns. To me, while they certainly *could* have been intended as anti-Semitic caricatures, it's not very clear: greed and sexual lust as species traits aren't definitive by themselves (especially since they're go-to "evil" traits), and the Ferengi's oversized ears as stand-ins for the traditional anti-Semitic caricature of oversized noses seems a bit of a stretch. The idea that the Ferengi represent "mere" 20th century capitalists, as frequently claimed, isn't readily dismissed. As such, I didn't include them in the list of examples.

Comment: While it is no excuse to his attitude whatoever it is worth noting that there is a limited number of people to place in the cast of the original star trek main crew at the very least so no matter what there would be groups without representation in the main cast. However, it would appear that the ones he chose to leave out due to space were also left out due to very poor personal opinions...

Comment: Hmm... I always thought of the Bajorans as Star Trek's "Space Jew race."

Comment: To a comical degree, the Ferengi embody common anti-semitic stereotypes: Nasty, unethical, clannish, indifferent to out-group norms, greedy, fetishizing hard currency, insular groups of them living abroad, etc. (I stress that none of those is actually true of real Jews). Sadly, it's baked into ST: W/o racial character traits, there's no reason for actors to wear rubber masks, hence little reason for ST to exist. In ST's futuristic "socialist" utopia, a "merchant class" race must be unpleasant. I wonder if a Philippine audience might see them as ethnically Chinese, or just arbitrarily weird?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I think you've hit the nail on the head.  Growing up in a culture in which Jewish people were unknown, I never even knew these were considered Jewish stereotypes, and my grandfather certainly would have used a term derogatory of Chinese people to describe the Ferengi if he ever saw them in DS9.

Comment: On the idea of the Ferengi representing 20th Century capitalists:  they are *explicitly* compared to "ocean-going Yankee traders of 18 and 19th century America" by Cmdr Data during their introduction in "The Last Outpost", and described as some sort of cross between Pirates and the East India Tea Company...

Comment: Probably worth noting here that "ferengi" (Turkish) and various similar words ("feringhi" in Hindi and Urdu, "farang" in Thai, etc) are used in a wide range of languages to denote western Europeans (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franks#Legacy).

Comment: @MasonWheeler: No way. Ferengi are definitively the space jew race. Bajorans are more like Jehova's witnesses married to Shinto. Reading, interpreting, and following dogma by the letter even if it doesn't make any sense or costs their life, and funny spirits/demons everywhere, some living outside spacetime, and some coming out of the clouds or living in stones or objects. Or caves.

Answer (score 89):

Gene Roddenberry was an active atheist, as per this quote:

> I condemn false prophets, I condemn the effort to take away the power of rational decision, to drain people of their free will - and a hell of a lot of money in the bargain. Religions vary in their degree of idiocy, but I reject them all. For most people, religion is nothing more than a substitute for a malfunctioning brain.

For this reason, there isn't a lot of religion portrayed in *Star Trek*, or at least the Federation. That said, there are [many references](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/inconsistencies/religion.htm) to religion in *Star Trek*. As for why the original series didn't portray any Jews specifically, it could be because Roddenberry seemed to [dislike the Jewish religous culture](http://jewishjournal.com/opinion/164916/) more than other religions (which didn't prevent him from hiring Jews like William Shatner and Leonard Nimoy).

Even so, numerous Jewish characters have in fact appeared in [several *Star Trek* novels](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Jew), which may or may not be considered canon:

- Darya Bat-Levi, in *Well of Souls* by Ilsa J. Bick, identifies as Jewish and discusses the religion at length.
- David Rabin, in *Vulcan's Forge* by Susan Shwartz (who is also Jewish) identifies as of "Earth Israeli descent". Though some Israelis are not Jewish, "David Rabin" is a Hebrew name, suggesting he is.
- Aaron Stemple, in *Ishmael* by Barbara Hambly, has a Hebrew name, and does not eat pork (which is forbidden in Judaism).
- Harb Tanzer, in Diane Duane's *The Wounded Sky* and *Spock's World* speaks fluent Yiddish (an East-European Jewish language, lit. Jewish).
- Myron Shulman, in *Recovery* by J.M. Dillard, has funeral conducted in accordance with Jewish tradition, including a minyan (ten men) reciting Kaddish (an Aramaic prayer used in Judaism).
- Jael Rabinowich, in *The Final Reflection* by John M. Ford, has a Yiddish name and uses the Hebrew phrase "Shalom aleichem" (lit. "Peace be upon you", colloquially, "Hi, how are you")
- David Steinberg, in *Yesterday's Son* by A.C. Crispin
- Lena Goldblum, in *Star Trek Log 5* by Alan Dean Foster, the Jewish roommate of M'Ress who plays with a dreidel (a spinning top associated with the festival of Chanukah).
- Saul Weinstein, in Brad Ferguson's *Crisis on Centaurus*, uses Yiddish expressions.
- Dora Grayson in *Strangers from the Sky* by Margaret Wander Bonnano. A Professor Grayson (Amanda Grayson's great-great grandfather) states that his wife, Dora, was Jewish.
- David Gold, captain of the USS da Vinci and his wife, Rabbi Rachel Filman, in the *Star Trek: Starfleet Corps of Engineers* series identify as Jewish, as do their descendants.

Comment: You should probably include the Nimoy quote from Valorum's link that explains why Roddenberry's atheism is relevant here: "Gene was anti-Semitic, clearly. Roddenberry had Jewish associates; Bill (Shatner) and I were both Jewish, as were others. To be fair, Roddenberry was anti-religion. And apart from being a ethnic-cultural entity, Jews, to him, were a religious group. But I saw examples not only of him practicing anti-Semitism, but of him being callous about other peoples' differences as well."

Comment: Yes, it would be terrible to [try to drain someone of a lot of money](http://mentalfloss.com/article/28895/star-trek-theme-song-has-lyrics).

Comment: This didn’t stop James Kirk from praising Christianity in the second-season episode “Bread and Circuses,” written by Roddenberry and Gene Coon. On other occasions, notably *Star Trek V*, Kirk said he did not believe in God.

Comment: The documentary "Chaos on the Bridge" pointed out the hillarious paradox of Roddenberry hating religion... and then introducing a god (Q) in the pilot for TNG.  Of course, said "god" spends the entire series trying to get humanity to worship him (or, at least, the Enterprise bridge crew) with dismal results.  :-)

Comment: @JBH because Q is a debunking/deconstruction of God.  Roddenberry did that all the time, it's a classic trope in Star Trek: all-powerful being shows up, then they spend the rest of the episode/movie/series  "pulling back the curtain" and revealing  him to be a huge, unGodlike jerk of poor character generally.  Just once I want to meet the all-powerful being that's kindly, integral, of impeccable character, quotes Buddha on philosophies of life, says Buddha never claimed to be a god, and readily admits s/he has no idea who God is.

Comment: @Harper: How do you feel about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Watches_the_Watchers ?

Comment: The Federation humans mostly have religious backgrounds, repeatedly saying "my god" and other similar references to their god on many occasions in many episodes.

Comment: @einpoklum As if atheists never utter "my god", that is more a cultural thing derived from religion than directly tied to a believe in god.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Atheists raised in a religious society or by a religious family, yes. Otherwise, no.

Comment: @einpoklum Given the federation derives from our society, it is not impossible that such utterances are just cultural holdovers instead of an indication of religious belief.

Comment: @einpoklum I'm an atheist, my parents were atheists.  It's really hard to describe England as "religious".  I say "My God", as an oath.

Comment: @user76377: It's not hard, England is a country with a deeply-rooted religious culture, strewn with chruches, where most people believe in a god (or at least, used to until recently; I don't follow polls about this). Plus, isn't your head of state, the queen also the head of the national church?

Comment: In so very many ways, Roddenberry created a vision of a universe that was far better than himself.  The more I hear about the guy, the less and less respect I have for him.

Comment: For the record, **none** of the prose novels are canon.

Comment: It's worth noting a complete absence of, say, Latinos, Muslims, Hindus/South Asians even though, individually or as a whole, they realistically comprise a good chunk of human kind. The Expanse does a better job at showing a realistic future, but then hindsight is always 20-20. Count it on Roddenberry's attitudes (quite elitist if we are honest) as well as the show being a product of its times (regardless of how avant garde it was.)

Comment: @luis.espinal Say what you want about Roddenberry but *Star Trek* was, at the time, hailed as groundbreaking in terms of diversity. Not for nothing does it ostensibly\* it feature the first interracial kiss on TV. The importance of that shouldn’t be overstated but it was certainly intentionally taboo-breaking. In hindsight its utter *lack* of diversity is obvious but it was ahead of its time.

Comment: Well, if you look at the end of my comment, I do acknowledge that it was 'avant garde', ahead of its time. I'm explaining that *despite that*, despite the groundbreaking Kirk/Uhura kiss, it was still a product of its time. I mean hell, the scene had to be re-scripted to make it as if the kiss was involuntary and against their will. I take nothing from the social strides of the show, but I won't be adding anything to the reality of it either.

Answer (score 23):

It may be noted that:

> With between 14.5 and 17.4 million adherents worldwide,[6] Judaism is the tenth largest religion in the world.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judaism[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judaism)

http://www.jewishdatabank.org/Studies/downloadFile.cfm?FileID=3394[2](http://www.jewishdatabank.org/Studies/downloadFile.cfm?FileID=3394)

It is believed that the present world population in 2018 is about 7,600,000,000.

http://www.worldometers.info/world-population/[3](http://www.worldometers.info/world-population/)

Therefore, the larger estimate of the Jewish population is about 0.00228 of the total world population.

So one person out of every 436.78 should be Jewish.  So how many total characters are there is *Star Trek*?  Eliminating extraterrestrial characters, how many characters are there in *Star Trek*?

The 2016 estimated population of China is about 1,403,500,365 people, or about 0.1846 of the estimated world population in 2018 - one person out of every 5.417.  Do 0.1846 of all *Star Trek* characters seem Chinese?

The 2016 estimated population of India is about 1,324,171,354 people, or 0.1742 of all the people in the world in 2018 - one person out of every 5.740.  Do 0.1742 of all *Star Trek* characters seem Indian?

These two examples show that while *Star Trek* may be better than most American shows in depicting the diversity of the world population, the cast of *Star Trek* characters is far less diverse than the world population in the 20th and 21st centuries.

Since Jews mostly look like European or Mediterranean people, though there are Jews looking like members of every human race, and since most most actors cast in *Star Trek* productions look like European or Mediterranean people, telling Jewish characters apart from non Jewish characters would be difficult without religious or cultural references.

And only a small percentage of *Star Trek* characters refer to their ethnic, national, religious, or cultural backgrounds.

And I point out that in TOS, and to a lesser degree in other *Star Trek* productions, alien planets often had populations that looked like Earth Humans, and in fact usually looked like "white" or "Caucasian" Earth Humans.  And since there are a number of planets in the United Federation of Planets with alien populations, It is probable that many of them have populations that look like Earth Humans even though those planets weren't colonized by Earth.  Thus the Federaton should be full of people who look like "white" or "Caucasian" or other Earth Humans but are more of less native to those planets and not descended from colonists from Earth.  Human looking people who probably don't share cultural, linguistic, or religious practices with Earth Humans.

So how can you tell which random Human looking characters actually are Earth Humans and which are aliens who merely look like Earth Humans?  How can you estimate the percentage of characters who are Earth Humans as opposed to merely looking like Earth Humans?

If many of the *Star Trek*  characters who look like Earth Humans are aliens who merely look like Earth Humans and have cultures different from any Earth cultures, the proportion of Jewish characters among *Star Trek* characters would be even lower than it would be if all Human-looking characters actually are Humans.

Therefore, I do not think that there are statistical grounds for considering Jewish characters to be under represented in *Star Trek*, nor do I consider Jews the first group that people should worry about being underrepresented in *Star Trek* - they should be more like number 100 or something on the list of underrepresented groups.

Comment: This is a perfectly logical and reasonable argument, that unfortunately entirely misses the reason there aren't many Jewish characters in Star Trek.

Comment: I have more trouble thinking of a Star Trek character that *doesn't* refer to their ethnic/national/cultural background - it's often pretty hamfisted, like with Chakotay, Sisko, or Picard.

Comment: @Adamant Answering a question. < Informing the questioner why the question is moot.

Comment: @RubelliteFae - It's not moot. It so happens that there is a perfectly sensible reason (several, really) not to have seen Jews in Star Trek - which has nothing to do with the *actual*, decidedly less sensible reasons, for their absence.

Comment: There are roughly 6 million Native Americans but they still made Chakotay.

Comment: @Shamshiel: How does Sisko refer to his ethnic/national/cultural background?

Comment: Exactly, Why isn't there any arab or eskimo or nordic characters? Answer that and you'll have the answer to why there wasn't a jewish character.

Comment: @workoverflow: For what it's worth, Julian Bashir at least has an Arabian name.

Comment: I don't remember many Italians, either.  Or Canadians, eh?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper That last name could be arabic/turkish/farsi/pakistani so not really an example.

Comment: @workoverflow - You don't think 7 of 9 is supposed to be "Nordic"? She wasn't born on Earth, sure, but her name was Annika Hansen, her father's was Magnus Hansen, etc.

Comment: @workoverflow - If the answer is, "Roddenberry and some other people didnt like Inuit and Arab people much," then it would certainly be the same answer.

Answer (score 6):

Since Jews have been subject to horrible discrimination and persecution, any portrayal of their perceived ethnic characteristics would need to be done particularly carefully and respectfully.  As with any ethnic portrayal, there would be risk in taking it too far into caricature (as in Chekov's exaggerated Russian-ness), leaving the ethnic characterisics in the realm of stereotype (Scotty), or not developing the traits sufficiently (for which Picard, with not much French except his name, is sometimes criticized).  The writers and showrunners might not have wanted to take this risk in the case of Jews, since the issue of Jewish ethnicity is more charged than others.

Comment: I'm downvoting, unfortunately. Not only is this not backed up by quotes or anything, but I am not sure it's likely.  Jews have faced "horrible discrimination and persecution," but so have many other groups represented early on in *Star Trek*: Africans, Asian-Americans, and so forth. As far as being charged, in the United States issues surrounding African-Americans are certainly more charged than those surrounding Jews.  While it's not impossible that writers *could* use this reasoning, it would have to be supported.

Comment: Picard was plenty French!

Comment: Yes ... and in the films was shown visiting the family home, picking grapes, ... and given Star Trek's “universal translators” kick in so often, perhaps he was in fact speaking French the whole time. Or perhaps in the twenty-fifth century, they all speak English...

Comment: @WillCrawford: He was shown doing that in the series.

Comment: @einpoklum Oops.